# How to get elements that have at least one direct child text node

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a function that returns all elements with an immediate child text node -

```
function getAllElementsWithDirectTextNode() {
    var matchingElements = [];
    var allElements = document.body.getElementsByTagName('*');
    for (var i = 0, n = allElements.length; i < n; i++) {
         if (allElements[i].childNodes !== null) {
             matchingElements.push(allElements[i]);
         }
    }
    console.log(allElements);           
}
```

However, this is not working. I think it has to do with the 5th line (the if statement). If the element has no direct text node children but does have a direct element child that has its own child text, I do not want to include it.

EDIT: I tried Praveen Kumar's solution with the following DOM, and the console prints all the elements in the body. However, I was expecting to only see div.div1, span.span2, div.div3, and button. Am I doing something wrong?

```
<div class="div1">
   this is direct text
   <span class="span1"></span>
</div>
<div class="div2">
    <span class="span2">this is span text</span>
</div>
<article></article>
<div class="div3">
    <span class="span3"></span>
    this is direct text, child #2
</div>
```

Comment: You're testing whether it has any children, but not testing whether the children are text nodes.

Comment: @ajm: Now I understand what you are looking for. There can be whitespace text nodes in the DOM under each element as the html gets formatted by editors or the authors. You are looking for a solution which ignores these whitespace and considering only relevant text. I have modified my answer to address your actual intent. There is a jsfiddle added as well

Comment: @ajm: if you want to see all elements with an immediate text node (whitespaced or not), you should remove the whitespace filtering from my code.

Comment: @ajm Please mark whichever solution that worked for you as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jsfiddle with NodeIterator](https://jsfiddle.net/santon/a8akuzga/)

[MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Whitespace_in_the_DOM)

```
$(function () {
var textNodeIterator = document.createNodeIterator(
document.body,
NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,

function (node) {
    if (is_ignorable(node)) return NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT;
    return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
});
var matchingElements = [];
var currentNode;

while (currentNode = textNodeIterator.nextNode()) {
    //console.log(currentNode);
    if (currentNode) {
        //console.log(currentNode.nodeType + "-" + currentNode.textContent);
        if (!isParentAlreadyMatched(currentNode.parentNode)) matchingElements.push(currentNode.parentNode);
    }
}
console.log(matchingElements);

function is_all_ws(nod) {
    // Use ECMA-262 Edition 3 String and RegExp features
    return !(/[^\t\n\r ]/.test(nod.textContent));
}

function is_ignorable(nod) {
    return (nod.nodeType == 8) || // A comment node
    ((nod.nodeType == 3) && is_all_ws(nod)); // a text node, all ws
}

function isParentAlreadyMatched(parentNode) {
    for (var i = 0; i < matchingElements.length; i++) {
        if (matchingElements[i] === parentNode) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
});
```

Comment: Is there a way for this to work with regular Javascript and not jQuery?

Comment: Nevermind; I removed the $ and outer parentheses then gave the function a name.

Comment: @ajm: The only JQuery reference is the ready function. Remove that to use window.onload(function() {}) or use a function name as you did

Answer (score 3):

You need to check if they have a `childNode` with `nodeType` of `Node.TEXT_NODE`:

```
function getAllElementsWithDirectTextNode() {
  var matchingElements = [];
  var allElements = document.body.getElementsByTagName('*');
  for (var i = 0, n = allElements.length; i < n; i++) {
    if (allElements[i].childNodes !== null) {
      for (var j in allElements[i].childNodes)
        if (allElements[i].childNodes[j].nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
          matchingElements.push(allElements[i]);
          break;
        }
    }
  }
  console.log(allElements);           
}
```

Comment: `childNodes` is a list of nodes, you can't test its type.

Comment: @Praveen: It is nodeType not nodetType. Correct the typo.

Comment: @Praveen,@ajm This solution will not work. Whenever there are exactly three childnodes for an element, it will misfire as Node.TEXT_NODE equals 3. I have added a second jsfiddle for a 'for' loop solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to test whether any of the children are text nodes. So you need to loop through all the children, testing their type.

```
function getAllElementsWithDirectTextNode() {
  var matchingElements = [];
  var allElements = document.body.getElementsByTagName('*');
  for (var i = 0, n = allElements.length; i < n; i++) {
    if (allElements[i].childNodes !== null) {
      var children = allElements[i].childNodes;
      for (var j = 0, m = children.length; j < m; j++) {
        if (children[j].nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
          matchingElements.push(allElements[i]);
          break; // don't need to check the remaining children
        }
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(allElements);
}
```

Comment: you have an extra semi-colon in your for loop

Comment: @Barmar: Change Nodes to Node. Not letting me edit for a single character.

Answer (score 1):

[jsfiddle with a for loop solution](https://jsfiddle.net/santon/95v3sn9z/)

```
 function getAllElementsWithDirectTextNode() {
    var matchingElements = [];
    var allElements = document.body.getElementsByTagName('*');
    for (var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++) {
        for (var j=0; j < allElements[i].childNodes.length; j++) {
            if (allElements[i].childNodes[j].nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                if (is_all_ws(allElements[i].childNodes[j])) continue;
                matchingElements.push(allElements[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(matchingElements);
}

function is_all_ws(nod) {
   // Use ECMA-262 Edition 3 String and RegExp features
   return !(/[^\t\n\r ]/.test(nod.textContent));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The answers provided so far are fine, but a bit dated.
There are some modern ECMAScript and DOM features you can use nowadays:

- [`querySelectorAll`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [`Array.from`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)
- [Destructuring assignment](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [`filter`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [`some`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
const getAllElementsWithDirectTextNode = () => Array.from(document.body.querySelectorAll("*"))
  .filter(({ childNodes }) => Array.from(childNodes)
    .some(({ nodeType, textContent }) => nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE && textContent.trim()))
```

The [`.trim`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) check is there to test if removing white space from both ends of the text node still produces a non-empty string.
Remove it if you also want to include white space only results:

```js
const getAllElementsWithDirectTextNode = () => Array.from(document.body.querySelectorAll("*"))
  .filter(({ childNodes }) => Array.from(childNodes)
    .some(({ nodeType }) => nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE))
```

The [`Node.prototype.childNodes`](//dom.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-dom-node-childnodes) getter will *never* return `null`, so any comparison with `null` is superfluous.